# Add parameters to GET form by just changing the form action url

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, struts2

First of all I tried many approaches with Jquery/javascript, so i was able to change the action of a form but was not able to add paramaters to it dynamically :

```
<form id="rfForm" name="rfForm"  action="./">
    <input type="hidden" id="sessionKey" name="sessionKey"></input>
    <button id="downloadRF" style="visibility:hidden">Download</button>
</form>
```

now i have a javascript function **getAllParams()** which will calculate some parameters dynamically and return their value as a string like : cefId=-1&cefMilestoneId=4304&dt=12/31/2016&stDate=01/01/2016

```
$("#downloadRF").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "./downloadFASReport.action";
        $("#rfForm").attr('action',url+getAllParams());
        $("#rfForm").submit();
        });
```

Now before this form submit, if i debug in chrome:

```
>document.getElementById('rfForm').action
www.example.com/downloadFASReport.action?cefId=-1&cefMilestoneId=4304&dt=12/31/2016&stDate=01/01/2016
```

But in the actual Url call it doesn't add any parameters and the Url that it hits is simply : www.example.com/downloadFASReport.action?

**How is it getting overridden, is there a solution ? I can't do a ajax call since i have to generate and download some excel/binary file (which i can't store on server).**

**Also:**
I tried having a hidden text field and then appending all these parameters (cefId=-1&cefMilestoneId=....) as a string to it before form submit but during form submit, it encodes everything in unicode fashion which seems fine since it assumes all text params to be text value.

Comment: Try `$("#rfForm").attr('action',url+getAllParams()).ready(function(){$("#rfForm").submit()});`

Comment: Could you add your Struts-Action? How do you handle the dynamic params there?